# How can I correctly manage local storage data in a Next.js project when switching user profiles?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, local-storage

I'm working on a React/Nextjs application where I'm using a custom useLocalStorage hook to manage local storage for user profiles. I'm trying to mimic a chatgpt app.

However, I'm encountering an issue where the local storage data of the new profile seems to retain the values of the previous profile, leading to incorrect behavior.

Here's a brief description of how my application is structured:

I have different user profiles. Each profile has it's own key, for example: profile1-chats, profile2-chats an so on.
I'm using the useLocalStorage hook with a dynamically generated key based on the current user's profile.

When a user switches profiles, the new profile is correctly set in the application state.

I'm using a Provider to have access to this values in my app.

```
export const ChatProvider: React.FC<ChatProviderProps> = ({ children }) => {
  const [userProfile, setUserProfile] = useState<ProfileType>(
    UserProfiles.Profile1
  );

  const [chats, setChats] = useLocalStorage(
    `${userProfile.title}-chats`,
    initialState
  );

// ....
```

This is the custom hook I'm using to handle localStorage, after doing some investigation I figured out that this is the way to do it in Nextjs

```
// CUSTOM HOOK TO HANDLE LOCAL STORAGE IN NEXTJS
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const useLocalStorage = <T>(
  key: string,
  initialState: T
): [T, React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<T>>] => {
  const [state, setState] = useState<T>(() => {
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
      try {
        const item = localStorage.getItem(key);
        return item ? JSON.parse(item) : initialState;
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error parsing local storage data:", error);
      }
    }
    return initialState;
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
      try {
        localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(state)); // I think the problem is here, when i change profile, the state has the values of last profile and it is setting that values to the new profile key
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error saving data to local storage:", error);
      }
    }
  }, [key, state]);

  return [state, setState];
};

export default useLocalStorage;
```

This is the component from which I am changing the user profile

```
const SelectProfileModal = ({
  isOpen,
  onClose,
  onConfirm,
}: SelectProfileModalProps) => {
  const { userProfile, setUserProfile } = useChatContext();
  const router = useRouter();
  const [selectedProfile, setSelectedProfile] =
    useState<ProfileType>(userProfile);

  const handleOnSave = () => {
    setUserProfile(selectedProfile);
    router.push("/");
    onClose();
  };

  return (
    <Modal show={isOpen} onHide={onClose}>
      <ModalHeader closeButton>
        <Modal.Title>Select Profile</Modal.Title>
      </ModalHeader>
      <ModalBody>
        <ListGroup>
          {AvailableProfiles.map((profile) => (
            <ListGroup.Item
              key={profile.id}
              action
              variant="dark"
              onClick={() => setSelectedProfile(profile)}
              active={selectedProfile.id === profile.id}
            >
              {profile.id}- {profile.title}
            </ListGroup.Item>
          ))}
        </ListGroup>
      </ModalBody>
      <ModalFooter>
        <Button variant="secondary" onClick={onClose}>
          Cancel
        </Button>
        <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleOnSave}>
          Select
        </Button>
      </ModalFooter>
    </Modal>
  );
};
```

**The problem I'm facing is that**, even though I'm switching profiles successfully in my application state, when I switch to a different profile the the local storage seems to be retaining the data from the previous profile, causing unexpected behavior.

I suspect that the issue might be related to the way I'm initializing the local storage for the new profile when the user switches. However, I've reviewed my code and the useLocalStorage hook, and they seem correct.

I'm new in Nextjs.

I'm seeking advice on how to troubleshoot this issue. Specifically:

How can I ensure that the local storage is correctly initialized for the new profile?

I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions to help me resolve this issue. If you need to see specific sections of my code or additional details, please let me know.

Stack:

```
    "next": "^13.4.12",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
```

Thank you for your help!

Expected result:
I ask a question using Profile1, it is correctly stored in profile1-chats key of localStorage, then I switch to Profile2, a new key in localStorage should be initialized with an empty `[]`.
If I ask a question using Profile2 it should be stored in its corresponding localstorage key.

Current result:
I ask a question using Profile1, it is correctly stored in profile1-chats key of localStorage, then I switch to Profile2, a new key in localStorage is initialized (profile2-chats) but values of profile1-chats are copied to profile2-chats.

Answer (score 0):

I think, in the code you provided, the state initialization is performed only once when the component is mounted, and it depends on the key provided as an argument. If the key changes after the component is already mounted, the state won't automatically update in response to the change in key.

Can you please add these lines of code too:

```
  // Use useEffect to watch for changes in the key
  useEffect(() => {
    if (key) {
      const storedItem = localStorage.getItem(key);
      if (storedItem) {
        try {
          const parsedItem = JSON.parse(storedItem);
          setState(parsedItem);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error parsing local storage data:", error);
        }
      }
    }
  }, [key]);
```

It is a rough work so please let me know in case this is shouting any error.